# Segmentation fault when reading a file in C

Tags: c

I try to read a file character by character on C and i get Segmentation fault, no idea why and how can i debug it..

```
int textdump(const char *filename)
{
    int count = 0;

    FILE *file;

    file = fopen(filename,"r");
    char letter;
    while(!feof(file)) {
        letter = fgetc(file);
        if (isprint(letter)) {
            printf("%c",letter);
            count++;
        }
        else {
            printf("?");
        }

    }
    fclose(file);
    return count;
}
```

Comment: [fgetc](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgetc) retruns an `int`

Comment: The `while(!feof(` is an anti-pattern. It's always wrong.

Comment: First of all you must check `if (file != NULL)`

Comment: @LPs that's actually the only way you can get a segfault with that code!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre `textdump(NULL);`

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @melpomene yeah, that too :) or `textdump((char*)234)`, that'll "work"

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so your code has a bunch of mistakes that are common in beginner code.

Here's how to do it along the same lines, but hopefully fixing the errors:

```
size_t textdump(const char *filename)
{
    size_t count = 0;

    FILE * const file = fopen(filename, "rt");
    if(file == NULL)
      return 0;
    while (1) {
      const int ch = fgetc(file);
      if(ch == EOF)
        break;
      if(isprint(ch) {
        putc(ch, stdout);
        ++count;
      }
      else
        putc('?', stdout);
    }
    fclose(file);
    return count;
}
```

This:

- Checks that the `fopen()` succeeds before relying on the file pointer being valid.
- Uses the proper type for `fgetc()`'s return value, which is `int`.
- Corrects the `while(!feof()` anti-pattern.
- Uses `fputc()` for single-character output, lighter than `printf()`.
- Uses `size_t` to represent the count.

I'm not saying this is *optimal*, it still does single-character reading for instance (but buffered so it shouldn't be too bad). But it should be better.

Comment: I don't think `"rt"` is a standard open mode.

Comment: The `(unsigned char)` cast is redundant.

Comment: @melpomene I've seen warnings about that some times, which is why I include it out of habit. It's weird since the `isXXX()` functions all take `int`, of course. I'll remove it in the interest of avoiding cargo-culting. Thanks.